# set permissions for ssh user and www-data in laravel to execute cache:clear command

Tags: laravel, caching, permissions, debian, laravel-9

I have a problem with laravel 9 and cache permissions.
This is the situation:

- I have www-data user used by apache
- I have user_composer user I use it to connect with ssh (he also belongs to www-data group)
- Laravel cache folders (`storage/framework/cache/data/*`) have 755 permissions and they belong to www-data:www-data

The problem is that when I connect with ssh and I try to execute `php artisan cache:clear` command I get permissions error cause cache folders belong to www-data.

How can I execute that command with ssh? Should I have to connect with "www-data" user to the server? I would like to not do that.